# Bar plot of daily counts taken at odd times

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have some data containing event counts taken at various times:

```
time,counts
2023-10-21 19:30,4936
2023-10-22 22:24,4950
2023-10-23 23:07,4966
2023-10-25 03:44,4981
```

My aim is to make a Vega-Lite specification for making a bar plot that estimates the day counts. For instance, for 2023-10-22, the count is something around 14, and for 2023-10-24 we need to infer that it is around 13 from the neighboring data points.

For turning the cumulative counts into diffs, I can use the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60537685/5085211), but I still need a way to convince it to estimate the daily counts. What I have now is the following:

```
      var vlSpec = {
          $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
          data: {
              url: "/counts.csv"
          },
          transform: [{
              window: [{
                  op: "lead",
                  field: "counts",
                  as: "b1"
              }]
          }, {
              filter: "isValid(datum.b1)"
          }, {
              calculate: "datum.b1 - datum.counts",
              as: "diff"
          }],
          encoding: {
              y: {
                  field: "time",
                  type: "ordinal",
                  title: "Day",
                  timeUnit: "binnedyearmonthdate"
              },
              x: {
                  field: "diff",
                  type: "quantitative",
                  title: "Daily counts"
              }
          },
          layer: [{
              mark: "bar"
          }, {
              mark: {
                  type: "text",
                  align: "left",
                  baseline: "middle",
                  dx: 3,
              },
              encoding: {
                  text: {
                      "field": "diff",
                      "type": "quantitative"
                  }
              }
          }]
      };
```

On a separate note, the resulting plot shows fine on desktop Firefox, but it does not show on Android Firefox or iPhone Safari. It does show on Android Chrome but not with slightly out-of-date versions of Vega/Vega-Lite, which also seems suspicious.